# Labview good practice and computation time

Tags: labview

I have two question for labview users. I'm quite new to this language, I would like to know if design like in the picture attached (extensive use of disable diagram structure) are:

- a good practice to separate part of code (I like the structure input/computation/output)
- does not imply extra computation time

[labview disable structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iOd2g.png)

Thanks in advance!

PS: sorry I had to hide some code not my will...(licensed)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the code is compiled and disable structures are ignored. But the best practise is to use subVIs (with proper connector pane and icon) to structure input/computation/output.

Everything that is connected to the left of your subVI connector pane is input. 
What you have in subVI is computation.
Everything that is connected to the right of your subVI connector pane is output.

Please have a look below: 
[image]

Comment: Disable structures may consume memory if VI block diagram is used. When you build application it automatically removes block diagram. So even from memory performance perspective it is not bad to use disable structures.

Comment: Inputs on the left and outputs on the right is a convention, which you should follow - but what actually makes the connector an input or an output is whether the corresponding terminal of the subVI is a control or an indicator, of course.

Comment: Thank you guys!
Great comment that helped my design, I use a mix of both methods, disable structure and subVi's.